# If I have an "ssh" account does that mean I can transfer files via "sftp"?

Tags: ssh, sftp

If I have an "ssh" account does that mean I can transfer files via "sftp"?

Comment: But the answer is probably yes.

Comment: And just as a tip, remember there is rsync. It may be installed or not, but in certain situations that works a lot better/easier, so if it works, just try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Probably Yes.

It's most likely you will be able to transfer files unless the server is specially restricted.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the actual settings on the server but usually when ssh is enabled, so if sftp and scp which I find quicker, but you need to know where the file is located on the remote system and know exactly what it's called

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. With at least OpenSSH, SFTP is a separate subsystem that can be enabled or disabled as desired. You will have SCP available though.